# Removing empty rows in Magento products ordered report

Tags: php, magento, report

I was wondering how one would go about removing empty rows from the **Reports->Porduct->Ordered** that ships with the Magento Community edition?

Standard is that Magento shows "No records found for this period".

Tried to search on this topic on different forums but haven't been able to find anything.

Any suggestions, tips or links?!

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking exactly.  If you're getting "No records found" then what do you want to remove?

Comment: Sorry for the that, I mean that I just want to show dates where there has been actual orders and hide all the dates where there are "No records found".

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

`/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/report/grid.phtml`

Locate these lines (starting around line 236 in CE1.5.1):

```
<?php else: ?>
            <td><?php echo $_index ?></td>
            <td colspan="<?php echo $numColumns ?>" class="empty-text <?php
echo $this->getEmptyTextClass() ?> last"><?php echo $this->getEmptyText() ?></td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Change to:

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanx, will try it out tonight!